# change phpMyAdmin Dump Generation Time timezone

Tags: phpmyadmin, timezone, dump

when i use the phpmyadmin to dump a mysql database. 
The commentline generation time is very helpful. However, how can i change it to my current timezone instead of UTC +00:00.

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1

### -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net

-- Host: localhost

### -- Generation Time: Aug 06, 2013 at 03:49 PM

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change the server system variable time_zone using

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;

or alternatively you can specify a default timezone for the system to use at server startup by running --default-time-zone=timezone.

The documentation on mysql time and date implementations discuss this in some detail.

here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

and here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone